# If-else clause in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, if-statement

I wish to add a new record in my Oracle database and update it if it already exists.

I am using an If-else clause to achieve this .

**Below is my code :**

```
DECLARE
  any_rows_found number;
BEGIN
  select count(*)
  into   any_rows_found
  from   reports
  where  report_id=27;
  IF(any_rows_found > 1)
  THEN
  UPDATE reports set
        TITLE = 'Check user entered keywords have valid resource link',
       CATEGORY = 'zData checks',
       DISPLAY_ORDER= 9120,
       QUERY ='...',
       CONTENT_SEQ=1,
       DELD=0,
       ADMIN_ID=1,
       DATE_UPD = to_timestamp('05-FEB-15 01.44.53.753311000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') 
      WHERE REPORT_ID = 27;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO reports (REPORT_ID,TITLE,CATEGORY,DISPLAY_ORDER,QUERY,DESCRIPTION,CONTENT_SEQ,DELD,ADMIN_ID,DATE_UPD)
VALUES (27,
        'Check user entered keywords have valid resource link',
        'zData checks',
        9120,
        '...',
        1,
        0,
        1,
        to_timestamp('05-FEB-15 01.44.53.753311000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'));
  END IF;
```

This throws following error as seen:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
>          null pragma raise return select update while with
>           
>           << continue close current delete fetch lock
>          insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
>          merge pipe purge
>       06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>       *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You are missing an `end;` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add END; as the last line of the file to close off the BEGIN near the top.

Answer (score 1):

In your code is an END; missing to close the open BEGIN statement.

However it might be more interesting to rewrite your code to a merge statement that also exists in oracle.

See the following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) for more information about this.

Answer (score 1):

You just miss an "end;" at the file end.

But i have to say: You should also take a look at the Merge SQL DML Statment. 
Its does exactly wath you want and is directly implementet from the DBMS devs so we can suggest it will outperform self writen PL/SQL scripts.

For your script it will be:

```
    MERGE INTO REPORTS old USING (select report_id = 27,
     TITLE = 'Check user entered keywords have valid resource link',
           CATEGORY = 'zData checks',
           DISPLAY_ORDER= 9120,
           QUERY ='...',
           CONTENT_SEQ=1,
           DELD=0,
           ADMIN_ID=1,
           DATE_UPD = to_timestamp('05-FEB-15 01.44.53.753311000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM') FROM DUAL) new 
ON (old.report_id = new.report_id)
    when matched then update set
    old.TITEL = new.TITLE, 
    old.CATEGORY = new.CATEGORY, 
    old.DISPLAY_ORDER = new.DISPLAY_ORDER, 
    old.QUERY = new.QUERY, 
    old.CONTENT_SEQ = new.CONTENT_SEQ, 
    old.DELD = new.DELD, 
    old.ADMIN_ID = new.ADMIN_ID, 
    old.DATE_UPD = new.DATE_UPD
    when not matched then 
    insert (report_id, TITLE, CATEGORY, DISPLAY_ORDER, QUERY, CONTENT_SEQ, DELD, ADMIN_ID, DATE_UPD) values (new.report_id, new.TITLE, new.CATEGORY, new.DISPLAY_ORDER, new.QUERY, new.CONTENT_SEQ, new.DELD, new.ADMIN_ID, new.DATE_UPD)
```